# how access base url in view file of CodeIgniter-3.1.6

Tags: codeigniter, base-url

How I can get application base URL in view template file?

I am using CodeIgniter-3.1.6 to build an application.

Comment: I think here you find all you need: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the URL helper (usually done in a controller or model):

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then your base URL is available in the view like this:

```
echo base_url();
```

Comment: This. You can also choose to add it to autoload in your config, then you don't have to include the helper in the controllers. (and don't do it in the model btw; either controller or autoload).

Comment: @Nic is right, but do be careful about autoloading everything.

Comment: It is also very important to set `$config['base_url']` in _/application/config/config.php_ for `base_url()` to work reliably.

Comment: @DFriend , that kind of goes without saying. Comment at the top of config/config say `WARNING: You MUST set this value!`

Comment: @BrianGottier, I agree it **should** go without saying. Based on the number of questions on SO and the CI Forum that directly relate to `config['base_url']` not being set I figured it was worth repeating.

Comment: i used $this->load->helper('url'); in controller and able to access base_url(); in views file